# css3 multiple backgrounds - shorthand for gradient and image

Tags: background, css, gradient, shorthand

Is there a way to use both a gradient & an image with the background **shorthand**? I have tried: backround: url(image_path) no-repeat top left, gradient -  but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loreley: you are doing it right. Here is a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ggULM/

The gradient syntax is quite delicate, and if you get anything wrong it will fail entirely. Test just with the gradient, and then add the image later.

A good practice in StackOverflow is sharing the specific piece of code so we are able to pinpoint to the exact source of the problem.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is really useful! I suspected it had to be something wrong in my syntax, and after some google searching I only found it to work without the shorthand - but now I got it.